# Customizing User Show Route in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes

I want, instead of /user/:id I want the default user route to be /user:created_at I was able to get /user:id to work (without the second /) however when I try to do :created_at I get an error.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Also, even though I have `match 'users:id', :to  => 'users#show', :as => :user, :via => :get` /user/1 still is a valid link since I have `resources :users` in my config/routes.rb. Is there a way to remove the default /user/:id when rails compiles the `resources :users`?

Comment: It's not hard to do what you're asking but, created at isn't a unique identifier for a resource. You should consider using another field if you can.

Comment: oh, the field has to be unique?

Comment: If two items have the same created at; which item should the resource /foo/:created_at refer to? It doesn't *have* to be unique but, should be if these urls represent a single resource (not a collection of all items with this created at.)

Comment: I agree with @jdeseno on this one.  You need to be 100% sure that you are using unique ID's in the path since that is how you are looking up your records.  You can always put the `created_at` in the path as well, but it shouldn't be the *only* ID in the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly you can either use to_param: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/to_param

so if you used in your user model

```
def to_param
   "#{first_name}_#{last_name}"
end
```

then user_path(@user) would generate /users/planet_pluto for example

to prevent a route to be generated by map.resources simply use :except

```
map.resources :user, :except => [:show]
```

hope that helps

Comment: For some reason, this doesn't change the route.

Comment: if you run rake routes can you still see the route for user#show being generated?

Comment: but if you defined a to_param method your :id will now whatever you specified in that method instead of the default database .id

Comment: how do you call the path helper in the view? it should be user_path(@user) or similar